# Application Request Routing (ARR) - Single Server Reverse Proxy(ish) Setup

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I have 1 webserver that has two .NET apps running on it.  These are set up on the server as app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com.

I would like to be able to take any request going to app1.mydomain.com/subfolder and rewrite it to app2.mydomain.com/subfolder using ARR.

I am having difficulty getting this to work on a single server, and all the ARR examples on the net seem to imply that I require another server dedicated to ARR sitting in front of the two web servers.

Is what I am attempting to do possible on one web server and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to hide these 2 sites.

Make ARR (default web site) the only listening on port 80. Make the 2 others listening only on the loopback (127.0.0.1) on different port (81 and 82 for example).
Then you can create rule on ARR to forward to app2 (create 2 farm in ARR with one server in each for example).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ARR here -- just setup a url rewrite to redirect requests to the correct app.

Failing that you want to look at the reverse proxy side of ARR, not the request routing. You need to enable the function globally, then you can:

- add a virtual site at app1.mydomain.com/subfolder
- Add a Url Rewrite reverse proxy rule to hit app2.mydomain.com/subfolder

Do note that reverse proxies don't mix with windows auth.